# horizontal slide button does not work with grid display

Tags: javascript, html, horizontal-scrolling

I'm working on a website, and want a horizontal carrousel function. I'm using the grid display, and after many tutorials I found a suitable way to implement this. For some reason this js does not work well with the grid display. I'm a novice and do not now much about java script.

As I mentioned, I played around with different ways to horizontal scroll. I realized that many of these implementations does not really work with grid, but I don't want to rewrite my entire code for this.

https://github.com/soberox/portfolio/tree/e944ffa81717bd95ec0e45e1588c4aaf1c72c32e

Comment: Hello @brawl-co, you seem to be quite new to web development, which is totally fine. But you even did not ask a question here. What are you aiming for? Do you expect someone check out your code and fix it? Maybe you should start with something more simple to get things going. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I'm, quite new to this, but I was aiming for somebody to take a look at my js file and see why the slider button does not work. I suspect that It might have to do with the grid display, but maybe there is a work around so I don't have to restart my development.